# Store PS command output to variable and Invoke-Command

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I need to store command output to pass it as variable in function later

```
#This works
[scriptblock]$command = {Get-EventLog system -newest 1  | Format-List}
$command.Invoke()
```

But when I try to Write-Host it fails

```
#This works
[scriptblock]$command = {Get-EventLog system -newest 1  | Format-List}
Write-Host $command.Invoke()
```

with output

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData
```

Line of the script in which I'm trying to use it is

```
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage('UserName user@my.domain','user2@my.domain','subjectText',($command.Invoke()) )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Format-List` return formatting objects. You need `Out-String` cmdlet to convert them to string:

```
$OutputAsString = $command.Invoke() | Out-String
```

Then you can pass that string into methods, which expect string as their input.

Answer (score 0):

`{ScriptBlock}.Invoke()` returns a `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<PSObject>` which is getting mangled by the `Write-Host` command.

If you use [`InvokeReturnAsIs()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.scriptblock.invokereturnasis(v=vs.85).aspx) you get correct results:

```
PS C:\> [scriptblock]$command = {Get-EventLog system -newest 1  | Format-List}
$command.InvokeReturnAsIs()

Index              : 141723
EntryType          : Information
InstanceId         : 1073748860
Message            : The Application Experience service entered the stopped state.
Category           : (0)
CategoryNumber     : 0
ReplacementStrings : {Application Experience, stopped}
Source             : Service Control Manager
TimeGenerated      : 9/8/2016 9:32:02 AM
TimeWritten        : 9/8/2016 9:32:02 AM
UserName           :
```